# Java - protected 'getters' vs. nested classes

Tags: java, inheritance, field, protected, nested-class

If I have a bunch of fields in a parent class that all need to be inherited by subclasses, is it better to have the subclasses nested in the superclass, make the fields protected rather than private, or use protected accessors? Or some other alternative?

Comment: As this depends heavily on your usecase, could you please elaborate a little more on that?

Comment: I have a superclass (Employee) that holds a lot of data that is common for its subclasses (types of employee), as well as some pay/tax calculation methods (abstract and concrete). The subclasses do a lot of calculation that requires data from fields in the superclass. Very few of the fields need to be accessed from outside this family of classes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most easiest solution is make the superclass fields or instance variables protected, however, if you make them private you can always access them through getters and setters which conceptually is much more better because it adheres to the principle of encapsulation.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution would seem to be to make the fields protected, unless you have a compelling reason to do otherwise, just go with that.

Answer (score 1):

I think using protected accessors the best way and more common approach.

Answer (score 1):

If you want it to be accessible to a subclass you are left with only two options, public and protected. Protected is probably what you want. The below table applies when you use the `extends` keyword in java for inheritance.

```
               Access Levels

Modifier    Class   Package Subclass    World
public      Y       Y       Y           Y
protected   Y       Y       Y           N
no modifier Y       Y       N           N
private     Y       N       N           N
```

If you NEST the sub class in the super class then you can use private as well. This is because the inner class is PART of the parent class and therefore has access to private methods as well.

```
public class Parent {
    private int x = 5;

    //Not really a subclass
    private class NestedClass {
        public NestedClass() {
            int hax = new Parent().x; // Works!
        }
    }

    //More of a nestedclass than a subclass.
    private class SubClass extends Parent {
        public SubClass() {
            int stillHax = new Parent().x;
        }
    }
}
```

You you don't use inheritance until you use the `extends` or `implements` keywords so you probably want to have the SubClass extending the Parent class (in a different file) and the variables would have protected (or public) level access. Note that being in the same pakage or in the same class takes prority in the grid. The above two examples work because the other class in in the SAME class as the parent class.

**Just follow the grid, that is all.**

Answer (score 1):

There are cases that exposing protected fields or protected accessor methods make sense.  So it all depends on your design for the parent class, and how do you want the child class to make use of your parent class.

However, one that that is for sure: "is it better to have the subclasses nested in the superclass" <- This is rarely a correct choice.